# Can someone explain what this System.ArgumentException error means?

Tags: c#, database, razor, webmatrix

I have this code:

```
//check if the user have any previous medical record.
var firstMedical = false;
    var sql="SELECT * FROM Medical WHERE CDSID = @0";
    var myMedical = db.QuerySingle(sql1, myCDSID);
    if (myMedical ==null){

                //if all the medical data is filled in, run sql1 to store all the answer into a database.
                var sql10 = "INSERT INTO Medical (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15, Q16, Q17, Q18, Q19, Q20, Alcohol, Medication, Details, CDSID) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23)";
                var medquestionnaire = new{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, alcohol, medication, details, myCDSID};
                db.Execute(sql10, medquestionnaire);

    } else {

                var sql2 = "UPDATE Medical SET Q1=@0, Q2=@1, Q3=@2, Q4=@3, Q5=@4, Q6=@5, Q7=@6, Q8=@7, Q9=@8, Q10=@9, Q11=@10, Q12=@11, Q13=@12, Q14=@13, Q15=@14, Q16=@15, Q17=@16, Q18=@17, Q19=@18, Q20=@19, Alcohol=@20, Medication=@21, Details=@22 WHERE CDSID=@23";
                var updquestionnaire = new{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, alcohol, medication, details, myCDSID};
                db.Execute(sql2,updquestionnaire); //error is highlighted on this line.

     }
```

Error is highlighted on `db.Execute(sql2,updquestionnaire);`.

Error is:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException
 : No mapping exists from DbType <>f__AnonymousType0`24[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object]
   to a known SqlCeType.
```

I do not understand what this error means and Webmatrix does not really explain this error clearly at all. How should I interpret that error, and fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to pass all the vars directly on the Execute line?

Comment: I wanted to try...but i found the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since db.Execute expects an array of objects as the second parameter try changing your `new` statement to explicitly create an array of objects.  Something like this for example...

```
var updquestionnaire = new object[] {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, alcohol, medication, details, myCDSID};
```